# I need a free or cheap and easy to install SQL administration website. Recommendations?

Tags: tools

Since I don't have TCP/IP access to my database--I just have a connection string that works from my ASP.NET pages--I need some sort of administrative web page or pages, or a whole website that lets me do as many actions as possible inside my database, such as executing arbitrary SQL, generating scripts, creating tables, etc.

Any advice?

If it works with SQL 2005, that would be best, but I'm willing to try solutions targeting SQL 2000 or SQL 2008.

Answer (score 2):

Is this not a question that would fit better for stackoverflow.com?

Here is a admin tool that you can try:
SQL Server Web Tools - http://sqlwebtools.codeplex.com/

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't know about this, it looks better than it's previous incarnation.

This is the perfect question that lies on the edge of server administration, web site administration, software development and web applications.  A strong arguement could be made to move to any of the four sites and close it on all of them.